# Why does VS 2008 sp1 install abort on Win7 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

What can you do if you get the following error when installing Visual Studio 2008 sp1 in Windows 7 RC?

```
Operation Aborted
```

Comment: Don't close this, SO is supposed to be a repository of useful information for programmers.  If he'd written this as 'why does VS install abort' and then posted his own answer, would that have been better?

Comment: dude. Post it as a q & a like will says.

Comment: Agreed; post the answer separately to the question. I consider this sort of question acceptable, but it needs to be done in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while installing Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows 7 RC 7100, run this as administrator:

```
reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient\Windows\DisabledSessions /va /f
```

Afterwards Visual Studio 2008 SP1 will install correctly.

**I copied this from the original question, just to make it a proper question/answer... marked as community wiki**

Answer (score 0):

[Download this update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d8eb4921-891a-4b5e-973f-0b96e6ccf376&DisplayLang=en) and install it before you install sp1 on to visual studio 08